# Determine $f$ such that $ann\left(N\right)\subseteq ann\left(M\right)$ ($ann\left(M\right)\subseteq ann\left(N\right)$ resp.)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f$ be an $R$-homorphism from $R$-module $M$ to $R$-module $N$. Determine $f$ such that $ann\left(N\right)\subseteq ann\left(M\right)$ ($ann\left(M\right)\subseteq ann\left(N\right)$ resp.)

Help me some hints. Thanks a lot.:)